# Pandas udf error on EMR: class "io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf"'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, pyarrow

I'm trying to use a pandas udf on a Jupyter notebook on AWS EMR to no avail.
First I tried to use a function that I did, but I couldn't get it to work, so I tried some examples of answers to other questions I found here, but I still couldn't get it to work.
I tried this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyarrow

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "A", "X1"),
    (2, "B", "X2"),
    (3, "B", "X3"),
    (1, "B", "X3"),
    (2, "C", "X2"),
    (3, "C", "X2"),
    (1, "C", "X1"),
    (1, "B", "X1"),
], ["id", "type", "code"])

schema = StructType([
    StructField("code", StringType()),
])


@F.pandas_udf(schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def dummy_udaf(pdf):
    pdf = pdf[['code']]
    return pdf

df.groupBy('type').apply(dummy_udaf).show()
```

And I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

I tried without the import pyarrow and I get the same error. I also used other codes from answers about this topic and the result was the same.

In the bootstrap shell script I have a pip install line as follows:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas==0.24.2 pyarrow==0.14.1
```

I've tried with pyarrow 0.15.1, but nothing changed.
Dou you have any idea what is causing this error? Thank you!

Comment: Making  pdf[['code']] you are selecting this column on dataframe. When making a groupby you need to make an aggregation(mean or sum for example). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually, this is a code from another post with a similar question that was solved. I can't make it work for my function or any function and this case was posted as a simple example. I could change the function to a sum and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following versions

`sudo python3 -m pip install pyarrow==0.14 pandas==1.1.4`